# Linux permission in directories

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, centos

I installed Apache in my server and it all looks fine. The problem is that everytime I create a folder/file it does not have 777 permission, I need to use chmod to every folder/file I create to assign 777 permission. How can I create a permission rule that will be the default to new files/folders ?

Comment: Why do you want everything 777 permission? It is a bit risky security-wise...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't and you **shouldn't** even if you could.  Having any file on the file system with `0777` as the mode is a very bad idea.

The slightly longer answer is that the Apache process controls the mode that it creates new files with as the third argument to [open(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) or by using [fopen(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html).  In the latter case, the mode is `0666` by default.  Whatever mode is passed in is further modified by the process's *[umask](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/umask.html)* value.  If a process has a sane umask (such as `022`), then the result of opening a file with `fopen` will be a file with its mode set to `0666 & ~022 = 0644`.  I guess if the process were to use `open` to create a file with `0777` and the process umask was set to `0`, then the file that it creates would have `0777` as the resultant mode.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree 777 is not a good idea, the answer is umask:

```
umask 000
```

I recommend the following at least so not everyone in the world (well, with access to that machine) can write there:

```
umask 002
```

Oh, and these don't inherit by the directory.  Use ACLs instead to get inheritence.  ACL tools vary from OS to OS.  Try "setfacl" or "chacl".

Comment: Note that modifying the umask only masks whatever mode the file is created in by the program.  If a file is created with RW perms across the board (`0666`), then clearing the umask will not set the missing bits.  It can only discard bits that are set.

Comment: Very true.  On the other hand, most programs use the standard 0666 permission set when creating files and 0777 for directories and executables, unless there is a very specific reason to do otherwise (such as security concerns).